Is there any way to access adskMasked debugInfoUrl content?
Recently, Autodesk introduced adskMask for secure debugging in Design Automation.
Below is the link for blog post:
introducing-adskmask-secure-debugging-design-automation
In this scenario, after implementing adskMask flag as "true", all the URLs are masked. If a Design Automation job failed, as a developer, I can retrieve a link to a debug folder zip file using "debugInfoUrl" from  response of GET Workitem. However, I am unable to access this URL for debugging. How can I access this masked URL? Is there any way to do so?
I tried to open the link for "debugInfoUrl" from  response of GET Workitem and encountered a permission issue - access denied. I want to access this debug folder to clearly understand the issue for the failed job.
Here is another link for reference:
troubleshot-failure-job
Thanks!

if adskMask flag is defined as "true", all URLs and credentials in the report.log will be masked. But you don't have to define this flag in the WorkItem payload at all, you will see all the URLs without masking.
